# If two price series are cointegrated but not correlated, how do I find the hedge ratio?

Tags: cointegration, pairs-trading, mean-reversion

Mathematically, what is going on here?

Comment: I think this is a valid question, but you should give us more information before we can comment.

Comment: What additional information would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

If two price series are cointegrated, you can run the linear regression to calculate the hedge ratio.

The linear regression is in the form:
$$y = \beta X + \epsilon$$

where,
$y$ is the dependent variable, $X$ is the independent variables, and $\beta$ is the slope that we want to estimate and $\epsilon$ is the error term.

In Python, the OLS function from the statsmodels package is used to calculate the hedge Ratio:

```
statsmodels.api.OLS (dependent_variable(y), independent_variable(X))
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the hedge ratio you can run the Johansen Cointegration test and the eigen-vector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue would give you the hedge ratio, you can see with a bit mathematical intuition that it means “The best linear combination of the two series to maintain a stationary series”. The eigenvector would ideally be something like (1, -ve) for a pair since hedge ratio has to be negative. Also before this you’d need to check whether the original pair was individually non-stationary.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the case, when one time series is a constant equal to zero, and the second time series is stationary. You still can run regression to find the hedge ratio is zero, and you don't need to hedge a stationary price with a constant.

Comment: So if I have two non-stationary cointegrated series, they must be correlated? That makes sense intuitively, but I don't know if there's a counter-example I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by correlated. Mine was just an example, I'm sure it's possible to contrive another example, where both series are non-stationary, but the correlation is pretty low.